# Am I using 1 Way or 2 way SSL

Tags: ssl

> root@XXXXXX:/var/tmp# curl --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 -v
> https://example.com:8443/health --cacert Internal_Root_CA.cer
>
> - Trying 10.50.65.56...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to example.com (10.50.65.56) port 8443 (#0)
> - ALPN, offering h2
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: Internal_Root_CA.cer   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> - ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: C=US; ST=ZZZ; L=CCC; O=Company; CN=example.com
> - start date: Sep 29 22:30:19 2022 GMT
> - expire date: Sep 27 22:30:49 2024 GMT
> - subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
> - issuer: O=Company; CN= Issuing CA
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
>
> > GET /health HTTP/1.1
> > Host: example.com:8443
> > User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> > Accept: */*
> > < HTTP/1.1 200  < Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 < Content-Length: 0 < Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2022 18:33:10 GMT <
>
> - Connection #0 to host mdm-dev.gcp.aexp.com left intact

Am I using 1 way or 2 way SSL? THe REST API is developed using Spring boot.
I have to pass in the Root CA for the Call to work.

Comment: Looks like 1-way to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 1-way SSL because a) you don't give a client certificate to use and b) the server does not even request one (no CertificateRequest message from server).